# SQL Contains From Table Column

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, contains, sql-like

I have two tables in a database. Both have columns named "Company Name".
I want to compare between these columns for any similarities in their names.

For Example : `Table1.CompanyName = 2i Ltd` /// `Table2.CompanyName = 2i Limited.`

Comment: Your question is unclear. What would your expect as outcome of your query?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Postgre, etc?

Comment: I have two columns from two different tables which contain names. For instance Column 'Company Name' from Table 1 contains 'ABC Ltd.' AND Columns 'Company Name' from Table 2 contains 'ABC Co. Ltd.'. What I want is a query which outputs those names which are similar but not equal to each other. I have tried LIKE "*[CompanyName]*" but I did not manage.

Comment: So you are asking for a fuzzy match. Which database platform are you using?

Comment: You'll need to define exactly what you mean by similar. Occurence of characters, occurrence of strings, semantntic similarity, phonic similarity ... I don't know of anything defined in standard SQL, what engine are you using?

Comment: I am using Access Database. Occurrence of strings.

Comment: Soundex may help http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Soundex

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean: how to join these together and compare the equality or something fuzzy.

You do it like this using Oracle Text which allows fuzzy matching:

```
select  t1.CompanyName
from    Table1 t1
join    Table2 t2
on      contains(t1.CompanyName, t2.CompanyName) > 0
```

In Access there are possibilities, but you will have to write it your own. Check out [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_database/microsoftaccess/article.php/c13137/Fuzzy-Matching-Demo-in-Access.htm) (code to much to paste).

Answer (score 0):

Let's create two sample tables to prepare our data

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (CompanyName VARCHAR(35))
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (CompanyName VARCHAR(35))
GO
INSERT INTO #Table1 (CompanyName)
SELECT '2i Ltd'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Xyz Ltd'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Abc Inc'
GO
INSERT INTO #Table2 (CompanyName)
SELECT '2i Limited'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Xyz Lmtd'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZZZ Corp'
```

And a partial match SELECT query (I have used **LEFT** 4 characters to find similar company name in table 1.

```
SELECT 
        t1.CompanyName,
        t2.CompanyName

FROM #Table1 t1
JOIN #Table2 t2
ON t1.CompanyName LIKE '%' + LEFT(t2.CompanyName, 4) + '%'
```